# SPA ReactJS social registration with HelloJS and PassportJS

Tags: node.js, oauth, passport.js, hello.js

I'm facing a problem related to oauth authentication using [NodeJS](https://nodejs.org/en/). The main concern is how to connect all to my current architecture. Lets me explain it a little bit.

I have a Cloud API which is a REST API to serve and manage the data. I also have the web client developed in [ReactJS](https://facebook.github.io/react/) (an SPA). My main goal is to allow social authentication without redirect or without to leave the page. For this, I'm using [HelloJS](https://adodson.com/hello.js/) and the [oauth proxy](https://github.com/MrSwitch/node-oauth-shim) in the same Cloud API.

Taking for example my Facebook App, the workflow is like:

1. The user clicks signup with Facebook
2. The [oauth proxy](https://github.com/MrSwitch/node-oauth-shim) serve as "handshake".
3. Facebook sends back the token to the web app.

At this point, this approach is working perfectly for me. My main concern is how do I send the token to the Cloud API for registration?, obviously I could add a middleware in the Cloud API to automatically register the user in the database, however I still need to invoke the authentication from the web client in order to exchange that token for a JWT token.

Yes, I'm using [JWT](https://jwt.io/) for communication with the REST API. I would like to allow local registration and social registration (Facebook, Twitter, and so forth).

It seems odd to me to trust in the token received from the web app without ensure that it is real and not expired. I thought to check it with [passportjs](http://passportjs.org/).

Advices or recomendations?

Thanks.